# Splice an array when key_value same?

Tags: php, arrays, split, hashmap

My sorted array needs to be split up so that each created array has all of those associated with that value.

```
Array (
    [NAME] => Array
    (
        [0] => Fooaz
        [1] => bzdsfdasfz
        [2] => Fooooooooo
    )

    [DESCRIPTION] => Array
    (
        [0] => Foo
        [1] => Foo
        [2] => Barrrr
    )
)
```

For example, from that array I want to get two arrays. One containing:

```
[NAME]=>Array([0] => Fooooooooo), [DESCRIPTION]=>Array([0] => Barrrr):
```

The other containing the remaining elements.

**What's an efficient way of doing this?**

Comment: Array key [NAME] always have three values ? and always need third value into new array ?

Comment: The position the value in `DESCRIPTION` always corresponds to that same position in all other keys

Comment: http://php.net/array_shift gives you the first element of an array (you have two arrays). The rest is up to you for anything *efficient*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = Array (
    'NAME' => Array
    (
        0 => 'Fooaz',
        1 => 'bzdsfdasfz',
        2 => 'Fooooooooo'
    ),

    'DESCRIPTION' => Array
    (
        0 => 'Foo',
        1 => 'Foo',
        2 => 'Barrrr'
    )
);

$arr1 = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $arr1[$key][] = array_pop($arr[$key]);
}

print_r($arr);
print_r($arr1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array_pop():
http://codepad.org/GeP6OEtf

```
<?php

$arr=array(
"NAME"=>array('a','b','c','d'),
"DESC"=>array('A','B','C','D')
);

$newarr=array();
foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
    $newarr[$key]=array(array_pop($arr[$key]));
}
print_r($arr);
echo "\n-------------\n";
print_r($newarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use extract function.

```
extract($array);
```

this will give you two arrays automatically.

[reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: can you provide a sample  related to this question ?